# How to remove a DOM element or select from a $(this).html() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the caret within an html element, either ▲ (▲) and ▼ (▼).

So I have used (it is within a separate function

`console.log($(this.html()))`

Which returns:

`Phone<span id="sort-caret">▲</span>`

Now, if I would like to remove the span entirely from this html element How would i do that?

Furthermore if I wanted to select the actual caret for use in comparison how could I do that?

**Update**:

Just to make the answers more relevant. How can I select the caret from within the html:

```
console.log($('#sort-caret', this).html());
```

Gives:

`undefined`

Comment: Can you share your html too?

Comment: Just as an aside, you'd might be better off using `class="sort-caret"` rather than `id="sort-caret"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the dom element and just get text:

```
 var s = 'Phone<span id="sort-caret">▲</span>';
 var r = /<(\w+)[^>]*>.*<\/\1>/gi;
 console.log(s.replace(r,""));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a9fEm/)**

And to remove the span from DOM itself:

```
 $('#sort-caret').remove();
```

To get span text in current context,use:

```
 $(this).find('span').html()
```

Comment: The code for selecting the caret, is actually Selecting `Phone` Instead. I would like to select the `▲`. Do I need to use a regular expression, could I not `console.log($('#sort-caret', this).html());` gives `undefined`

Comment: @StevieG:have you tried `$(this).find('span').html()`

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to remove the span?

```
$("#sort-caret").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I would like to remove the span entirely from this html element
>   How would i do that?

Using jQuery [**remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) you can select it and remove it, similar to this:

```
// you can drop the ",this" if context is not important and no repeated ids are in your HTML.
$('#sort-caret', this).remove();
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9nsK/) - Removing the Span

---

> Furthermore if I wanted to select the actual caret for use in
>   comparison how could I do that?

`.html()` contains the HTML content of the span. Place it in a variable for later use, similar to this:

```
var caret = $('#sort-caret', this).html();

//or

var caret = $('#sort-caret').html();
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kMK3C/) - Get caret from span

---

Why your code `console.log($('#sort-caret', this).html());` is not working and returns `undefined` is impossible to tell without all of the relevant HTML **and** script.

The `#sort-caret` element might not exist at the time you are running your code...

or...

The `#sort-caret` element might not exist in what ever context `this` is.

Again though, without the relevant code it is hard to tell what `this` is and without all the relevant HTML it is hard to tell if the element exists at the time of the query or should be in that context in the first place or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(this).find('#sort-caret').remove()
```

> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aPJVB/)